# Spring Boot Redis - Lettuce is not creating connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am using spring-boot-starter-cache for redis interaction and below is the code which I am using to intialize the configurations :

```
@Autowired
    private LettuceConfigProperties lettuceConfigProperties;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();

        for (RedisNodeDetails nodeDetails : lettuceConfigProperties.getServers()) {
            if (nodeDetails.getPort() == null) {
                nodeDetails.setPort(lettuceConfigProperties.getDefaultPort());
            }
            clusterConfiguration.addClusterNode(new RedisNode(nodeDetails.getHost(), nodeDetails.getPort()));
        }
        clusterConfiguration.setPassword(lettuceConfigProperties.getPassword());

        if (clusterConfiguration.getClusterNodes().size() == 1) {
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
            standaloneConfiguration.setPassword(lettuceConfigProperties.getPassword());
            standaloneConfiguration.setHostName(lettuceConfigProperties.getServers().get(0).getHost());
            standaloneConfiguration.setPort(lettuceConfigProperties.getServers().get(0).getPort());
            var lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(standaloneConfiguration, createLettuceClientConfiguration());
            lettuceConnectionFactory.setShareNativeConnection(false);
            return lettuceConnectionFactory;
        }

        var lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfiguration, createLettuceClientConfiguration());
        lettuceConnectionFactory.setShareNativeConnection(false);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class)); // Customize based on your needs
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class))); // Customize based on your needs
        log.info("[LETTUCE] Initializing.....");
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LettuceClientConfiguration createLettuceClientConfiguration() {
        return LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
                .poolConfig(createPoolConfig())
                .clientOptions(clientOptions())
                .clientResources(lettuceClientResources())
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getCommandTimeout()))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientOptions clientOptions() {
        return ClientOptions.builder()
                //Controls auto-reconnect behavior on connections. If auto-reconnect is true (default), it is enabled.
                //As soon as a connection gets closed/reset without the intention to close it, the client will try to reconnect and re-issue any queued commands. This flag has also the effect that disconnected connections will refuse commands and cancel these with an exception.
                .autoReconnect(true)
                //Request queue size for a connection. This value applies per connection. The command invocation will throw a RedisException if the queue size is exceeded and a new command is requested. Defaults to Integer.MAX_VALUE.
                .requestQueueSize(lettuceConfigProperties.getMaxRequestQueueSize())
                .socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder()
                        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getSocketTimeout()))
                        .keepAlive(SocketOptions.KeepAliveOptions.builder()
                                .enable().idle(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getKeepAliveIdleTimeout())).build())
                        /**
                         * true to disable Nagle's algorithm, false to enable Nagle's algorithm.
                         * The Nagle algorithm processes data on the sending side of TCP applications by a method called Nagling.
                         * It detects small-sized messages and accumulates those messages into larger TCP packets before sending data across the wire.
                         * This process avoids the generation of unnecessarily large numbers of small packets.
                         * But this adds some latency sp we are disabling this
                         */
                        .tcpNoDelay(true)
                        .build())
                .timeoutOptions(
                        /**
                         * Options for command timeouts. These options configure how and whether commands time out once they were dispatched. Command timeout begins:
                         * When the command is sent successfully to the transport
                         * Queued while the connection was inactive
                         * The timeout is canceled upon command completion/cancellation. Timeouts are not tied to a specific API and expire commands regardless of the synchronization method provided by the API that was used to enqueue the command.
                         */
                        TimeoutOptions.builder()
                                .timeoutCommands() //true if commands should time out.
                                .connectionTimeout() //To apply connection timeouts declared on connection level. This will apply -1 as connection timeout in which case connection level configuration will be applied for command connections timeouts
                                .build()
                )
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Strategy interface to provide all the infrastructure building blocks like environment settings and thread pools so that the client can work with it properly.
     * ClientResources can be shared amongst multiple client instances if created outside the client creation. Implementations of ClientResources are stateful and must be shutdown() after they are no longer in use.
     */
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ClientResources lettuceClientResources() {
        return DefaultClientResources.create();
    }

    private GenericObjectPoolConfig<?> createPoolConfig() {
        GenericObjectPoolConfig<?> poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();

        // Maximum number of idle connections in the pool
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getMaxIdle());

        // Maximum number of connections that can be created in the pool
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getMax());

        //Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getMinIdle());

        //The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are no available connections and the getMaxActive() has been reached) for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception.
        poolConfig.setMaxWait(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getMaxWait()));

        //The minimum amount of time an object must sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction.
        poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(lettuceConfigProperties.getConnections().getMinIdleEvictTime()));

        //Whether to test idle connections for eviction
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);

        //The indication of whether objects will be validated before being borrowed from the pool. Keep this false as it will add some latency for every request
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(false);

        // Whether to test connections when they are returned to the pool
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(false);

        // Whether to test connections during the eviction process
        poolConfig.setTestOnCreate(false);

        // Whether the pool uses LIFO (last in, first out) or FIFO (first in, first out) for ordering idle objects
        poolConfig.setLifo(true);

        //If the pool is exhausted (no available idle instances and no capacity to create new ones), this method will either block if set to true
        //Or throw a NoSuchElementException if set to false
        poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);

        return poolConfig;
    }
```

When I am listing all active threads for lettuce only below threads were found :

```
"lettuce-eventExecutorLoop-1-1",
"lettuce-timer-3-1",
"lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1",
"lettuce-eventExecutorLoop-1-2"
```

I am using below properties for connection pool :

```
  default_port: 6379
  password: ********
  maxRequestQueueSize: 200000
  servers:
    - host: *.*.*.*
      port: 6379
  connections:
    max: 20
    minIdle: 5
    maxIdle: 10
    commandTimeout : 1000
    socketTimeout: 1000
    keepAliveIdleTimeout: 60000
    maxWait: 5000
    minIdleEvictTime: 60000
```

I have checked that LettuceClientConfiguration are intialized correctly and all properties are set accordingly but still it is not initializing connection pool. What could be the possible reason here? I have gone through all the documentations and only thing I found that we need to set property to false of shareNativeConnection which I already did. Any help would be appreciated.